# The geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

By given this matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}0&a&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

Why for any a which is not 0 the geometric multiplicity = 1?
and why for a = 0 the g.m. = 2?

I don't get it, and I'd like a short explanation how to calculate the geometric multiplicity in this case.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know the definition of geometric multiplicity?

Comment: @GitGud - Yes sir...

Comment: So what problems are you having in finding it?

Comment: I don't understnad how to calculate it...

Comment: @user2969278 I think you need to write down the definition first (I mean here), then you might understand.

Comment: @user2969278 Please tell me the definition of geometric multiplicty of the eigenvalue $0$ with respect to this matrix.

Comment: The geometric multiplicity is the dim(Null(A-XI)), am I right?

Comment: @user2969278 You're right if you know what $A$ and $X$ are here. Do you?

Comment: A is the matrix and by X I ment for Lambda.

Comment: @user2969278 OK, what is $\lambda$?

Comment: @GitGud - It is the eigenvalue...

Comment: @user2969278 OK, what eigenvalue?

Comment: @GitGud - I'm not sure... 1?

Comment: @user2969278 No. Do you know how to find the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: @GitGud - Yes sir, I need to find the characteristic polynomial. So then the eigenvalue is 0?

Comment: @user2969278 Yes, the only eigenvalue is $0$. Now getting back to $\dim(\text{Null}(A-\lambda I))$, can you simplify things a bit?

Comment: @GitGud - so I know there's only one eigenvalue and therefore the algebric g. = 1... and dim(Null(0)) = 0. Right?

Comment: @user2969278 You correctly said that $\lambda =0$, so where are you getting $\dim(\text{Null}(0))$ from?

Comment: @GitGud - dim(Null(A))? Null(A) is when Ax=0. So the Null(A) is {(0,0)} and therfore the dim is 1?

Comment: @user2969278 It can't possibly be $\text{span}\{(0,x_1),(x_2, 0)\}$ because these are two dimensional vectors and $A$ is $3\times 3$. I'm off now. Good luck.

Comment: I've edited... Isn't that only one?

Answer (score 1):

If the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is two which means that the dimension of the eigenspace of $0$ is $2$ then there's two linearly independent eigenvectors associated to $0$ and then the given matrix would be similar to
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and this is a contradiction. Think to the rank of the two matrices!

**Edit:** Notice that two similar matrices have the same rank, dimension of the kernel, characteristic polynomial, minimal polynomial, trace...